# how to write custom platform-specific code in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

For printing in printer purpose, I am using native code for Android in the android folder of flutter app. So I wanna create MethodChannel but in android activity, all these imports are not found. (showing  error)

```
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.BasicMessageChannel
import io.flutter.plugin.common.StringCodec
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
```

Comment: https://flutter.io/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages

Answer (score 0):

It is happening to me as well and I am still wondering why...
To solve it I open the project from the root, so not only the android libs are loaded but also dart and flutter libs:

[image]

I try adding the libs into graddle conf, but still not working... I hope this is useful for you